# Plot surface python with different width in mesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I' m trying to plot a 3d surface with python in fact i have this code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

def f(x,y):
    r=x**2 + y**2
    return r

n=4.
b=1.
a=-b
h=(2*b)/n
print h
hx=h ##This line##
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X = arange(a, b+hx, hx)
Y = arange(a, b+h, h)
n = len(X)
m = len(Y)
Z = zeros([n,m])

for i in arange(n):
    for j in arange(m):
        Z[i,j] = f(X[i],Y[j])
X, Y = meshgrid(X, Y)
ax.plot_surface(Y, X, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
plt.show()
```

This runs Ok and show me the graph I am looking. But when I change ##This line## into hx=h/2. And run it, the graph goes to hell, it's horrible and impossible to understand. I want to have a closer grid in X than Y axis. How I can do this??

Of course this is an example I am solving a partial differential equation, and i need to have a grid closer in one axis than the other one to have numerical estability.

Comment: as a side note `np.linspace` is a useful function (in place of `arange`)

Comment: It is also best to give a more descriptive explanation of the error than 'graph goes to hell'

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

You have flipped your dimensions

```
Z = zeros([m,n])

for i in arange(n):
    for j in arange(m):
        Z[j,i] = f(X[i],Y[j])
X, Y = meshgrid(X, Y)
```

works for any ratio of `n` to `m`.

With the function you have, you can use `numpy`'s broadcasting and write this whole section as

```
X, Y = meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = f(X,Y)
```

which is both easier to read and faster.

I would re-write this whole block of code as:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

def f(x,y):
    r=x**2 + y**2
    return r


n = 5
m = 10
b = 1.
a = -b

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X = linspace(a,b,n)
Y = linspace(a,b,m)

X, Y = meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = f(X,Y)

ax.plot_surface(Y, X, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
plt.show()
```